# Перезаписать текст в файле

Tags: c#

Написал код для вставки запятой перед словами. Как перезаписать текст в файле на текст с расставленными запятыми?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string path = @"D:\GITHUB\C#\111.txt";
        string s = File.ReadAllText(path);
        s = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(s, " который", ", который", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.None);
        s = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(s, " которая", ", которая", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.None);
        s = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(s, " которые", ", которые", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.None);
        s = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(s, " которое", ", которое", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.None);
        string appendText = s;
        File.AppendAllText(path, s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну замените `File.AppendAllText` на `File.WriteAllText`.

Comment: В вашем коде переменная `appendText` лишняя.

Answer (score 2):

Функция `File.AppendAllText`, если внимательно перечитать её название, *добавляет* текст, переданный ей в качестве аргумента, к данному файлу.

Если вы хотите *заменить* текст, воспользуйтесь функцией `File.WriteAllText`.